# How can I get relative date based on relative date by linux date command?

Tags: linux, date

Can I get "last monday based on 10 minutes ago" by linux date command ?

For example

- current time: 2016-02-09 00:05:00
- expected result: 2016-02-01 00:00:00

Comment: I believe you can't in a single command since syntax like `last monday` seems to always be relative to today. But you could use a short script that gives you the correct date based on whether `10 minutes ago` was a Monday.

Comment: ITYM _GNU `date`_ instead of _linux date_. linux is just an OS kernel software. There are several date implementations that can be compiled for Linux, the most common on non-embedded OSes that use Linux as their kernel is the one from the GNU project (part of GNU coreutils).

Answer (score 8):

If you have `faketime` and your `date` is dynamically linked:

```
faketime -f -10m date -d 'last monday' '+%F %T'
```

With `ksh93` (only builtin commands):

```
printf '%(%F %T)T\n' "$(printf '%(%Y.%m.%d)T' '10 minutes ago')-0 last monday"
```

Here, if it was last *Sunday* instead of last *Monday*, you could do:

```
date -d "$(date -d '10 minutes ago' +"%F -%u day")"
```

Or if it was last *Saturday*:

```
date -d "$(date -d '10 minutes ago' +"%F -%w day -1 day")"
```

But for last *Monday* or any other day of the week, it involves a bit of arithmetic:

```
eval "date -d \"$(date -d '10 minutes ago' +'%F -$(((%u+5)%%7+1)) day')\""
```

Otherwise, you can always do:

```
d=$(date -d 'last monday'); sleep 600; printf '%s\n' "$d"
```

;-)

Comment: The 2nd example doesn't give last Monday relative to 10m ago. Just a clarification for those who would miss the joke.

Comment: @Dani_l, depends how you look at it. At the time that command outputs a date, the date displayed would be the last monday relative to 10m earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in 2 date operations.  Here's a quick bash shell script:

```
TIME_TEN_MINUTES_AGO=`date -d '-10 min' +%T`

LAST_MON=`date -d 'last-monday' +%Y-%m-%d`

echo "NOW:      " `date "+%Y-%m-%d %T"`
echo "Last Mon: " $LAST_MON $TIME_TEN_MINUTES_AGO
```

This prints:

```
NOW:       2016-02-12 07:54:27
Last Mon:  2016-02-08 07:44:27
```

Comment: I think you missed the point. "10 minutes ago" could fall on the previous day. In that case, the "last monday" should be relative to yesterday.

Comment: Ahhh, that's true.  My bad.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem: given a date find the previous Monday.

(to rename the videos files of a show with its airing date on tv;

`DATE=$(youtube-dl -j $VID | awk -F\" '{print $28}')`)

I use BSD `date` on macOS and I've also installed GNU `date`.

It seems like `faketime` is the easiest solution for this problem:

`faketime $DATE date -v-mon +%F`,

`faketime $DATE gdate -d last-mon +%F`.

It can be done it with just GNU `date`, but it’s more complicated:

`eval "gdate -d \"$(gdate -d $DATE '+%D $[-%u+1] day')\" +%F"`.

You could also do it with BSD `date` only, even if it gets messy:

`date -j -f "%a %d %b %Y %T %Z" "$(date -j -r \
"$(date -j -f "%Y%m%d" "$DATE" +"%s")" -v-mon)" +"%F"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small script that solves the problem where 10 minutes ago is a previous day. I'm sure it could be done more elegantly though:

```
#!/bin/bash

DAY=`date --date='-10 min' +"%a"`
SEC=`date --date='-10 min' +"%s"`

if [[ "$DAY" == "Mon" ]]; then
    DDIF="7"
elif [[ "$DAY" == "Tue" ]]; then
    DDIF="1"
elif [[ "$DAY" == "Wed" ]]; then
    DDIF="2"
elif [[ "$DAY" == "Thu" ]]; then
    DDIF="3"
elif [[ "$DAY" == "Fri" ]]; then
    DDIF="4"
elif [[ "$DAY" == "Sat" ]]; then
    DDIF="5"
elif [[ "$DAY" == "Sun" ]]; then
    DDIF="6"
fi

EPOCH=$(awk "BEGIN {print $SEC-(86400*$DDIF); exit}")
date -d@"$EPOCH"
```

What this does is find out what day 10 minutes ago falls on. Finds out how many days removed that is from a Monday. Then multiplies that many days by 86400 (the number of seconds in one day) and subtracts it from the Epoch as based on 10 minutes ago. Finally it converts the epoch value back to standard format.

Like I said, not necessarily simple, one line, or elegant.

Comment: I think you missed by 7 :) If 10m ago falls on Monday, last Monday would be a week ago, not "today". DDIF should equal 7, not 0.

Comment: Ah yes. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Not too elegant but this should do the trick:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
export LC_ALL=C # makes sure we're using C locale even in subshells
day_10_minutes_ago=$(date -d '-10min' +%a) # stores which weekday it was 10 minutes ago
day_now=$(date -d +%a) # stores which weekday it is now
if [ $day_10_minutes_ago = "Mon" ]; then # if ten minutes ago it was Monday
    if [ $day_now = "Mon" ] # if it's still Monday
        date -d '-1week 00:00' '+%F +%T' # prints the date and the time it was one week ago at 00:00
    else # it can only be Tuesday before 00:10:00 AM
        date -d '-1week-1day 00:00' '+%F +%T' # prints the date and the time it was one week and one day ago at 00:00
    fi
else # it can only be Tuesday after 00:09:59 AM, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday or Sunday
    date -d 'last-monday 00:00' '+%F +%T' # prints the date and the time it was last Monday at 00:00
fi
```

Comment: Suppose today is Tuesday a few minutes after midnight. Then "10 minutes ago" is Monday. "Last Monday" relative to "10 minutes ago" would be the *previous* Monday, 8 days before today. Your condition misses this.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Absolutely, thanks. I think I've fixed it.